# How do i make my player move faster on land than in air while still having my sprint script working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

so I've been struggling with this for about 3 hours trying to make this work so excuse my spaghetti code.
this script is making the character move and also sprint. i cant see how to add more to this paragraph i belive ive made a pretty concise point and told helpers what my problem is

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift) && isGrounded)
{
    moveSpeed = 10f;
}
    
if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.LeftShift) && isGrounded)
{
    moveSpeed = 6f;
}
```

but it seem as after i added the script to slow down mid air sprinting ceased to work

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody rb;
    public Transform _camera;

    public float moveSpeed = 6f;
    float jumpForce = 5f;

    public LayerMask Ground;

    bool isGrounded;
    bool Landed;
    void Start()
    {

    }

    void Update()
    {
        //grounding
        isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y - 1, transform.position.z), 0.4f, Ground);
        Landed = isGrounded

        //facing direction
        Debug.DrawLine(_camera.position, transform.forward * 2.5f);

        //SPRINTING

        if (isGrounded == false)
        {
            moveSpeed = 2f;
        }
        else
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.W) == false)
            {
                moveSpeed = 6f;
            }
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift) && isGrounded)
            {
                moveSpeed = 10f;
            }
            if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.LeftShift) && isGrounded)
            {
                moveSpeed = 6f;
            }
        }
        //moving
        float x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * moveSpeed;
        float y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") * moveSpeed;

        //jumping
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && isGrounded)
            rb.velocity = new Vector3(rb.velocity.x, jumpForce, rb.velocity.z);

        //setting movement
        Vector3 move = transform.right * x + transform.forward * y;
        rb.velocity = new Vector3(move.x, rb.velocity.y, move.z);
    }
}
```

Comment: in the `else` part, your `&& isGrounded` are useless, because you already know it's `true` (precisely because you're in the `else` part)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some pseudo code could be:

```
if(isGrounded)
{
    moveSpeed = isSprinting
        ? 10f  // sprinting on ground
        : 6f;  // walking on ground
}
else
{
    moveSpeed = isSprinting
        ? 3f  // sprinting in the air
        : 2f; // moving in the air
}
```

Or reversely:

```
if(isSprinting)
{
    moveSpeed = isGrounded
        ? 10f  // sprinting on ground
        : 3f;  // sprinting in the air
}
else
{
    moveSpeed = isGrounded
        ? 6f  // walking on ground
        : 2f; // moving in the air
}
```